# insert IE conditional statement (comment) with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, if-statement, append

I tried to add a conditional statement for IE7 with jQuery, but it doesn't work dynamically (if it was hardcoded it worked, so I know this is related to the way jQuery is appending the actual "comment" of the conditional statement).

The code I'm using is this:

```
$("head").append("<!--[if IE 7]>");
$("head").append("<link>");
css = $("head").children(":last");
    css.attr({
    rel:  "stylesheet",
    type: "text/css",
    href: "css/IE7.css"
});
$("head").append("<![endif]-->");
```

My thought is that this is related to the `<` and `>`, maybe these need to be urlencoded?, how?

Anyone have a solution for this that doesn't involve targeting each CSS property with jQuery (there are tens of CSS fixes, so that won't be a solution).

Comment: Conditional comments are a *parse-time* thing. By the time your jQuery code runs, the page is already parsed, so it makes no sense to think about conditional comments at that stage. It's like asking how you stir the dough when you've already baked the bread. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks for the explanation, I was so focussed on getting the conditional statement comment to work that I didn't realize it wouldn't be parsed the common way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [`$.browser`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/) to check the browser version and act accordingly:

```
if ($.browser.msie && parseInt($.browser.version, 10) === 7) {
    $('head').append('<link>', {
        rel:  'stylesheet',
        type: 'text/css',
        href: 'css/IE7.css'
    });
}
```

Comment: @jackJoe: Or better yet, *don't* worry about specific *versions* of browsers. Rather, worry about (and test) *features*: http://kangax.github.com/cft/ But Darin shows you how to do the equivalent of what you actually asked.

Comment: That's a nice idea and does solve my problem, I didn't even think of that. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I'd opt for Conditionizr, it does all this for you as a standalone API and is more reliable than jQuery: http://conditionizr.com